# Create a protected room via Admin API

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is it possible to create protected rooms via the [admin API](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/)?

The `create_room` command from the docs only takes 3 parameters: `Name`, `service` and `host`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible!

```
POST /api/create_room_with_opts
{
  "name": "room1",
  "service": "muc.example.com",
  "host": "localhost",
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "members_only",
      "value": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

From here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#create-room-with-opts